# XOR Binary in PHP

Tags: php, xor

I want to XOR the binary but the result is still wrong xor xor example script:

```
function _xor($text,$key){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){
            for($j=0; $j<strlen($key);$j++){
                $text[$i] = $text[$i]^$key[$j];
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

and this is the result :

```
10011110
```

should result xor between

```
01100001
01100010
--------
00000011
```

please give me the right answer

Comment: You can't XOR a string with a string and expect it to behave like a bit. You should convert the pseudo-binary strings (ie: `'011000001'` is not a binary string) into an actual binary strings, and just XOR those directly.

Comment: @NullUserException: I just tested this, you can..

Comment: Also, your code can be written much more simply (and correctly) as `return $text ^ $key`.

Comment: @Evert How so? http://codepad.org/qH5t1Lv7

Comment: The output of that example is `0x01`.

Comment: @Evert Is that just a side effect of `'0'` and `'1'` being `0x30` and `0x31` or am I missing something here?

Comment: Doubt it. PHP is pretty crazy when it comes to casting. http://codepad.org/FK1dUY5W

Comment: @Evert I don't think so. `0x30 ^ 0x31 = 0b110000 ^ 0b110001 = 0b000001`. This can be verified using `'A' ^ 'D' = 0x41 ^ 0x44 = 0b1000001 ^ 0b1000100 = 0b0000101` http://codepad.org/rBJGO0jl

Comment: @Evert According [to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), "Be aware of data type conversions. If both the left-hand and right-hand parameters are strings, the bitwise operator will operate on the characters' ASCII values." So yes, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: @NullUserException You're completely right; I didn't realize `0x31` and `0x30` would have the same outcome :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function _xor($text,$key){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){
        $text[$i] = intval($text[$i])^intval($key[$i]);
    }
    return $text;
}

echo  _xor('01100001','01100010');
```

Before you use `^`, you should first convert string to int

There not need use two loops which are wrong, just one is ok.

Comment: if I want to repeat some binary numbers when inserted into this loop
[code]
function _xor($text,$key){ 
  for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){ 
    $text[$i] = intval($text[$i])^intval($key[$i]); 
  } 
  return $text; 
}
[/code]
example:

011000010110000101100001

01100010

======================

how to repeat as the binary number 01100010 in the first row?

Comment: @iwandede: sorry, I don't understand what you mean. define `repeat binary number` please.