# XOR - unexpected results

Tags: php

I use xor like this:

```
echo 1000 ^ 1111; //the result is 1983, but I expect 111
echo 0000 ^ 1111; //the result is 1111
```

Can anyone help me out? Thank you

Comment: You can watch this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14365224/685060

Comment: @lighter If you know a question is a duplicate, please flag it as such in the future. It helps the questioner and the community

Comment: @Machavity OK. I got it.