# Why xor results are different, 0 becomes 1

Tags: php, arrays, binary, xor

i want to make a program like the following picture
[image: pic1]
[image]

and this is my code

```
<?php

 $iv = 0;
 $Kunci = "U";

 $key =  dechex(ord($Kunci));
 $k =  sprintf("%08d",decbin(hexdec($key)));

 $c0 = sprintf("%08d", decbin($iv));
 $Cip= "0C52CCD7EDB3";
 $Cbs = array();
 $Cbs[0]= $c0;

 $Plaintext = array();
 $Cas = array();
 $P = array();  
 $m= 1;
 $n=1;

//$Cbs= 
$Csplit = str_split($Cip, 2);
$Cas= str_split($Cip,2);

        for ($i=0; $i<count($Csplit); $i++) { 

            $Cbs[$m] = sprintf("%08d",decbin(hexdec($Csplit[$i])));
            $m++;

        }



        for($i=0; $i < count($Cas); $i++){
            $Cas[$i] = sprintf("%08d",decbin(hexdec($Cas[$i])));
            $Cas[$i]=bindec($Cas[$i])>>1;
            if($Cas[$i] % 2 <> 0)$Cas[$i]+=128;
            $Cas[$i]=sprintf("%08d", decbin($Cas[$i]));

        }


 foreach($Cas as $cas_item) {
$prev_c = $Cbs[$n-1];    

$P[$n] = _xor($cas_item, $k);

 $P[$n] = _xor($P[$n], $prev_c);


$Plaintext[$n] = chr(bindec($P[$n]));

 $n++; 
 }

function _xor($text,$key){
for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){
  $text[$i] = intval($text[$i])^intval($key[$i]);

}
  return $text;
}

print_r($Csplit);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($Cbs);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($Cas);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($P);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($Plaintext);

?>
```

Cbs = before shift biner
Cas = after shift biner
and this comes out, the program code works but array 2 and array 5 are wrong. the binary bit code in front should be 0, not 1.
Output :
[image]

array 2 should be 01110000 instead of 11110000, and array 5 should be 01110100 but result is 11110100. why is 0 in front being 1?

Answer (score 2):

When shifting right, beware of the difference of signed and unsigned shift. (also called arithmetic or logical shift)

8-bit value 11101000 right shifted as signed will be 11110100.

The point is if you are shifting a signed value to the right, the uppermost bit is duplicated into the new bits moving in. If you are shifting unsigned values, the uppermost bits move in zeroes.

Languages that lack unsigned integer datatypes have another right-shift operator `>>>` to indicate that an unsigned (or 'logical') shift is meant. This is the case in PHP and in Java.

This only applies to right-shifts. Never to left. The point is that a right-shift will result in a divide-by-two behaviour.

Comment: so which part of the program code should I change so that the results are the same as the picture above

Comment: Have you tried swapping out the `>>` signed-shift operator for the unsigned one? And also consider if an 8-bit value is sign-extended to 32 bits before applying shift. I don't know how PHP behaves here.

Comment: I don't understand the intentions that have been signed and those that haven't been signed, can you give an example

Comment: For example, 11101000, interpreted as an unsigned-8bit is 232. Shifting right returns 01110100, which is 116. A division by 2. But, when looking at it as a signed-8bit value, it means -24. Right-shifting it with sign-extension of the upper bit makes 11110100, which is -12. Just what we want. When ignoring that and taking 01110100 as signed-8bit, it would be -140. Now what you'd expect when treating the right-sift as a div-by-2. For logical bit-ops, you most often want unsigned-shifts, but many languages only use signed or even sign-extend the 11101000 to 11111111 11111111 11111111 11101000.

Comment: thank you for explaining to me, I have got the solution